# WordPress not showing recent posts

Tags: posts, categories

For some reason, when a new post is published, it doesn't show up in its category page unless I am logged in. I built a custom theme, and have in no way specified anything that should cause this to happen. It's especially strange because they do show up when I'm logged in.

And, no, the posts aren't private.

This is how I've defined my loop:

```
 <div class="content-categories-wrapper">
   <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());

    endwhile;
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like there may be a caching plugin installed. If so, clear the cache.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Worked! So simple and yet I was fretting over my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there may be a caching plugin installed. If so, clear the cache.